# Mysql INSERT statement FAILING when POSTING large array

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I've been searching the internet and "pulling my hair out" for days over this.  It works fine on my XAMPP localhost and was working fine on my online testing server until I updated the PHP version and had to rewrite the code due to deprecated syntax.

Basically, I'm making a backend database for photography clients.  One of the tables is designed to store image information.  I haven't tried to store an actual image (BLOB of some sorts), I'm just looking to store "what and where".

What seems to be happening is if I try entering the contents of a shoot directory with several hundred images, when I hit input the screen changes, then instead of telling me how many were entered, it goes to a "418 unused" page saying

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

I've been trying to narrow down which buffers to increase or variables like "max_allowed_packet", "max_input_vars"... still no luck.  I've even tried comparing the phpinfo between the two servers to find out why one works and the other doesn't...

Here's what I'm doing... the listpage

```
<?php
// set page headers
$page_title = "Enter Images into Database";
include_once 'auth.php';

// get database connection
include_once 'config/fpaddb.php';
include_once 'objects/clients.php';
include_once 'objects/photoshoots.php';
include_once 'objects/images.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$colname_chk_Images = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['ShootId'])) {
  $colname_chk_Images = $_GET['ShootId'];
}
$colname1_chk_Images = "NULL";
if (isset($_GET['ShootFolder'])) {
  $colname1_chk_Images = $_GET['ShootFolder'];
}

$colname_get_Images = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['cID'])) {
  $colname_get_Images = $_SESSION['cID'];
}
$entered=0; //check for already entered images

?>
<?php
$dirname=$_SESSION['cIFolder'];
$Clogin=$_SESSION['Clogin'];
$ClientID=$_SESSION['cID'];
$_SESSION['CURR_CLIENT_ID'] = $ClientID;
$maindir=$_GET['ShootFolder'];
$ShootId=$_GET['ShootId'];
$dir=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."protect/clientfolders/".$Clogin."/users/".$Clogin."/images/".$maindir;
$_SESSION['dir']=$dir;
$dir2="/protect/clientfolders/".$Clogin."/users/".$Clogin."/images/".$maindir;
$dirt= "/phpThumb-master/";
$dirn= dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$filesArray=array_map('basename', glob($dir."/*.jpg"));
$lightbox_data= "FPAD_Lightbox";
$thumb =    "$dir2/";
$notThumb =   "$dir2/";
$ic = count($filesArray);
$_SESSION['SESS_TOTNUM'] = $ic;
$_SESSION['sID'] = $ShootId;
$sID = $_SESSION['sID'];

include_once 'header_a.php';
?>
<div class="container">
<?php
echo $_SESSION['SESS_TOTNUM']." images found ";
echo "for Shoot ID#: ".$_SESSION['sID']."<br>";
echo "*Note* - if input boxes come up GREEN, then images are already loaded into the database";
?>
<p>
<?php

$images1 = new Image($db);

$images1->ShootId = $colname_chk_Images;
$images1->directory = $colname1_chk_Images;
$images1->ClientID = $colname_get_Images;
$chk_Images = $images1->checkImages();
$get_Images = $images1->getImages();

$Images = array();

while ($row_get_Images = $get_Images->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $Images[] = $row_get_Images['image_name'];
    }
?></p>
<form method="POST" name="form1" id="form1" action="input.php">
    <table id="clientshoots" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-small">
  <tr>
    <th>image_id</th>
    <th>image_name</th>
    <th>image_path</th>
    <th>image_path_root</th>
    <th>image_size</th>
    <th>directory</th>
    <th width="auto">ShootId</th>
    <th width="auto">ClientID</th>
    <th>ClientName</th>
    <th>login</th>
  </tr>
  <?php $ic=0;
   for($i=0;$i<count($filesArray);$i++) { 
        $fileinfo = $filesArray[$i];
        $fname=$dir."/".$fileinfo;
        $fname2=$dir2."/".$fileinfo;
        $size = filesize($fname);
        $atime = date("F d, Y H:i:s", fileatime($fname));
        $mtime= date("F d, Y H:i:s", filemtime($fname));
        $perms=decoct(fileperms($fname) & 0777);
        $type=filetype($fname);
        $pth=realpath($fname);
        $name=basename($fname);
        $dn=dirname($fname2);
        if (in_array($fileinfo, $Images)) {
        $entered=1;    
        echo "<style type=\"text/css\">\n";
        echo "input {\n";
        echo "background-color:#00FF33;\n";
        echo "}\n";
        echo "</style>";
        } 
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="image_name[]" value="<?php echo $fileinfo; ?>" readonly/></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="image_path[]" value="<?php echo $dir; ?>" readonly/></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="image_path_root[]" value="<?php echo $dir2; ?>" readonly/></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="image_size[]" value="<?php echo $size; ?>" readonly/></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="directory[]" value="<?php echo $maindir; ?>" readonly/></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="ShootId[]" value="<?php echo $ShootId; ?>" readonly/></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="ClientID[]" value="<?php echo $ClientID; ?>" readonly/></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="ClientName[]" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['cName']; ?>" readonly/></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="login[]" value="<?php echo $Clogin; ?>" readonly/></td>
    </tr>
    <?php next($filesArray);
    $ic=$ic+1;
    } 

    $_SESSION['SESS_IC'] = $ic;?>
</table>
<?php if ($entered == 1){
  echo  "<a href=\"viewClient.php?ClientID=".$ClientID."\" class=\"btn btn-primary active\">Return</a>";
} else { 
  echo  "<input class=\"btn-primary\" style=\"background-color:\" id=\"Insert records\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Insert records\">";
}?>
<input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1">
<input type="hidden" name="sID" value="<?php echo $sID; ?>">
</form>
</div>
<br>
  <!-- /container -->
 <?php include 'footer_b.php'; ?>
```

and then the input.php page...

```
<?php
// set page headers
$page_title = "Enter Images into Database";
include_once 'auth.php';

// get database connection
include_once 'config/fpaddb.php';
include_once 'objects/clients.php';
include_once 'objects/photoshoots.php';
include_once 'objects/images.php';
include_once 'objects/ratings.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$sID = $_SESSION['sID'];
$ic = $_SESSION['SESS_IC'];
$ma = $_SESSION['SESS_CLIENT_MULTI'];
$gn = $_SESSION['SESS_CLIENT_GRPNO'];
$cID = $_SESSION['cID'];

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

    //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection

        function clean($str) {
        $str = filter_var(($str), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        return ($str);
    }

$image1 = new Image($db);   

$count = count($_POST['image_name']);
$fileinfo = clean($_POST['image_name']);

    //Check for duplicates
    if($fileinfo != '') {
            for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) { 
            $fileinfo = clean($_POST['image_name'][$i]);
            //echo $fileinfo;
            $image1->image_name = $fileinfo;
            $result = $image1->check4Dup(); 
            if($result) {
                if(count($result) > 0) {
                    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Image already entered into Database';
                    $errflag = true;
                }
                $result = NULL;
            }
            else {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
            next($count);   
            }
        }
$image1->ic = $ic;
$num = $image1->create();   

$colname_newImages = "-1";
if (isset($sID)) {
  $colname_newImages = $sID;
}
$image1->ShootId = $sID;
$newImages = $image1->countOneShoot();
$row_newImages = $newImages->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$totalRows_newImages = $newImages->rowCount();
$ic2 = $totalRows_newImages;
$_SESSION['SESS_TOTNUM_ENT'] = $ic2;
header("Location: rs_images.php"); 


include_once 'header_a.php';
?>
<div class="container">
<?php 
echo "Success! Number of images entered is ".$ic2; ?>
<br><br>
<p><input name="Verify" type="button" value="Verify Inputs" onclick="MM_goToURL('parent','rs_images.php');return document.MM_returnValue"/></p>
</div>
 <?php include 'footer_b.php'; ?>
```

And the Class file...

```
<?php

class Image{

        // database connection and table name
    private $dbh;
    private $table_name = "images";

    // object properties
    public $image_id;
    public $image_name;
    public $image_path;
    public $image_path_root;
    public $image_size;
    public $directory;
    public $ShootId;
    public $ClientID;
    public $ClientName;
    public $login;
    public $ic;

    public function __construct($db){
        $this->dbh = $db;
    }

    // Clean Function
    function clean($str){
        $str = filter_var(($str), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        return ($str);
    }

    // test function
    function test(){

        $ic = $this->ic;

        $i=1;
        $j=1;
        foreach ($_POST['image_name'] as $row=>$iname)
        {
            $image_name = clean($iname);
            $image_path = clean($_POST['image_path'][$row]);
            $image_path_root = clean($_POST['image_path_root'][$row]);
            $image_size = clean($_POST['image_size'][$row]);
            $directory = clean($_POST['directory'][$row]);
            $ShootId = clean($_POST['ShootId'][$row]);
            $ClientID = clean($_POST['ClientID'][$row]);
            $ClientName = clean($_POST['ClientName'][$row]);
            $login = clean($_POST['login'][$row]);
            $Clogin = $login."');";

            $i=$i+1;
            $j=$j+1;

            $qry1st = "INSERT INTO `images` (image_name, image_path, image_path_root, image_size, directory, ShootId, ClientID, ClientName, login) VALUES ";
            $sql_array = "('".$image_name."', '".$image_path."', '".$image_path_root."', ".$image_size.", '".$directory."', ".$ShootId.", ".$ClientID.", '".$ClientName."', '".$Clogin;
            //$stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($qry1st.$sql_array);
            //$stmt->execute();
            echo $qry1st.$sql_array;
        }

    }

     // create function
    function create(){

        $ic = $this->ic;
        $qry1st = "INSERT INTO `images` (image_name, image_path, image_path_root, image_size, directory, ShootId, ClientID, ClientName, login) VALUES ";

        $sql_array = array(); // This is where we'll queue up the rows

        $queue_num = 50; // How many rows should be queued at once?
        $i=1;       
        foreach ($_POST['image_name'] as $row=>$iname)
        {
        $image_name = clean($iname);
        $image_path = clean($_POST['image_path'][$row]);
        $image_path_root = clean($_POST['image_path_root'][$row]);
        $image_size = clean($_POST['image_size'][$row]);
        $directory = clean($_POST['directory'][$row]);
        $ShootId = clean($_POST['ShootId'][$row]);
        $ClientID = clean($_POST['ClientID'][$row]);
        $ClientName = clean($_POST['ClientName'][$row]);
        $login = clean($_POST['login'][$row]);
        if ($i==($_SESSION['SESS_TOTNUM'])) {
        $login_term = $login."');";
        }
        else
        {
        $login_term = $login."')";
        $i=$i+1;
        }

        $sql_array[] = "('".$image_name."', '".$image_path."', '".$image_path_root."', ".$image_size.", '".$directory."', ".$ShootId.", ".$ClientID.", '".$ClientName."', '".$login_term;

        // Add a new entry to the queue
        $c=0;
        if (count($sql_array) >= $queue_num)
        { // Reached the queue limit

        $addImages = $this->dbh->query($qry1st . implode(', ', $sql_array)); // Insert those that are queued up
        $addImages->execute();

        $sql_array = array(); // Erase the queue
        }//End if 

        }//end foreach

        if (count($sql_array) > 0) // There are rows left over
        {
        $addImages = $this->dbh->query($qry1st . implode(', ', $sql_array));
        $addImages->execute();
        }
    }

    function checkImages(){

    $query_chk_Images = "SELECT images.image_name FROM images WHERE ShootId = ? AND directory = ?";

    $chk_Images = $this->dbh->prepare ($query_chk_Images);
    $chk_Images->bindValue(1, $this->ShootId);
    $chk_Images->bindValue(2, $this->directory);
    $chk_Images->execute();
    return $chk_Images;
    }

    // create function
    function getImages(){

    $query_get_Images = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE ClientID = ? ORDER BY image_name ASC";

    $get_Images = $this->dbh->prepare ($query_get_Images);
    $get_Images->bindValue(1, $this->ClientID);
    $get_Images->execute();
    return $get_Images;

    }

     // create function
    function getImageID(){

        $query_rsImageID = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE ShootId = ? ORDER BY image_id ASC";

        $rsImageID = $this->dbh->prepare($query_rsImageID);
        $rsImageID->bindValue(1, $this->ShootId);
        $rsImageID->execute();

        return $rsImageID;
    }

     // create function
    function get_image_id(){

        $q = "SELECT image_id FROM images WHERE ShootId = ? ORDER BY image_id ASC";

        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($q);
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $this->ShootId);
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;
    }

    // create function
    function countOneShoot(){

        $query_newImages = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE ShootId = ?";

        $newImages = $this->dbh->prepare($query_newImages);
        $newImages->bindValue(1, $this->ShootId);
        $newImages->execute();

        return $newImages;
    }

    // create function
    function check4Dup(){

        $qry = "SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE image_name = ?";

        $result = $this->dbh->prepare($qry);
        $result->bindValue(1, $this->image_name);
        $result->execute();

        return $result;
    }
}
```

I've striped out all the extra stuff I've tried, like entering the info one record at a time, binding the Values with colon prefixed field names instead of the ?'s.  I've tried different loops.  I think it comes down to trying to push too much through one query... but then why does it work on XAMPP and why was it working fine with PHP 5.2?

I appreciate any light that can be shed on this.  This is my first ever post with regards to PHP, MySQL or anything site related, I've been learning this stuff as I go and had it 90% completed and debugged and when I put it online to do some real testing with the actual directories and client folders that's when I found out that between PHP 5.4 and 5.2, there have been a number of changes and I found myself rewriting almost every line to move up to either MySQLi or PDO/OOP.  After doing a lot searching around the internet I've opted for the OOP approach and still need to rewrite even more of the code above to clean things up a ton, but right now I'm troubleshooting the INSERT failure which I have not been able to solve on my own or with the help of all the forums, posts and blogs I've read to date.

Comment: This could be down to the maximum POST size set on the server it's deployed on.  Do you know how the server is configured, and is there much difference?

Comment: According to the phpinfo, it's "post_max_size = 65M"

Comment: I also noticed in the CLASS file I have above, the query code is doubled.

"$addImages = $this->dbh->query($qry1st . implode(', ', $sql_array));"

"$addImages->execute();"

I only need one or the other, not both... so I changed the first to prepare from query.  So that isn't the issue... I can get the code to work with a directory with 16 images... but one with over 100 it hangs for a second then triggers the 418.